# Here Weather API alternative black & white icon set

Tags: here-api

Currently i'm using here maps API for development purpose only. Now i want to know, if there are alternative weather icons (perhaps without color / black & White ones) available? I could easily make my own ones, but if there are already available, i would just use them.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Here doesn't provide any weather icons in the normal SDK. You can use the icons you get in the response of Destination Weather API.

```
https://weather.api.here.com/weather/1.0/report.json
?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}
&app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}
&product=observation
&name=Berlin-Tegel
```

The response of this would give you iconLink attribute which gives the image location. Read more about this in https://developer.here.com/documentation/weather/topics/example-weather-observation.html

Else you can try Mobile UI SDK. Read more about it in developer site -  https://developer.here.com/blog/mobile-ui-sdk-2.0-is-here-with-navigation

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not using the SDK, so currently i use the icons which i get in the response of the API call. This is the only icon set, which you provide?